# How can a model with a smaller engine produce more power?

Tags: power, torque, compression

I am from India, here we have Ford Ecosport. Tt has different models, out of which one model with less cc produces more power than a higher cc model (999cc and 125ps) & (1497cc 123ps). How is this possible? What are the advantages and disadvantages  of less cc more power vehicles?  [image]

Comment: Is the larger engine an older model still on sale? Newer engines are tuned to a higher standard and can produce the same or more power with less displacement...

Comment: Are they the correct specs you have shown there?  One has a heading for 1.0 GTDi which sounds like a diesel.

Comment: The lower compression ratio and the large RPM range with max. torque indicate that the 999cc engine is turbo- and/or supercharged while the other one is not.

Comment: @HandyHowie 6000 rpm and a 10:1 compression ratio don't sound like Diesel.

Comment: It is also direct injected.

Answer (score 6):

I am guessing that the smaller engine has a turbocharger and the larger engine doesn’t.  This would fit with the smaller engine having a lower compression ratio.

The turbo compresses the air entering the engine allowing more fuel to be added.  The small engine will therefore in effect have a larger capacity and will therefore be more powerful.

The smaller engine will likely have a small amount of turbo lag, whereas the larger engine will likely be more responsive at lower revs.

Insurance may be more expensive on the more “sporty” turbo engine.

After doing a bit of research, it looks like the generation 1 of the 1.0 had a supercharger and the generation 2 has a turbo charger, while the 1.5 is a normally aspirated.

Comment: I would agree. The "GDTI" moniker would also lend to this theory. The "T" is usually an indication of turbocharging.

Comment: You'll often find that insurance prices are linked to the displacement more than the horse power, so a turbo can give better value insurance than the larger engine.

Answer (score 3):

> how is it possible?

Turbo/ Supercharging, higher tuning, there are a lot of possibilities to make more power out of an engine.

> what are the advantages & disadvantages of less cc more power vehicles

Advantages of the "smaller" engine:

- Possibly less weight.
- Better fuel efficentcy
- Less material consumed in making it (but could be offset by added turbocharger)
- More power in high revs.

Disadvantages:

- More and complicated moving parts.
- Potentially less sturdy.
- Less torque in low revs.